# New Rasperry Pi setup by network cable /eathernet cable to notebook

Tags: raspbian

i have installed Raspbian os on SD card but cant able to get it connected Raspberry Pi 3 by my notebook over putty, connection using by only Ethernet cable without router or net connectivity

Comment: Can you ping the Pi's IP address from the PC and vice versa?

Comment: cant able to detect IP of Raspberry Pi, as i dont have moniter ,have only Ethernet cable and laptop

Comment: What operating system is the machine on the other end of the network cable using?

Comment: It's going to be little tricky but [this post explains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040128/hook-up-raspberry-pi-via-ethernet-to-laptop-without-router) it nicely.

Comment: it is windows 10